# Authentication with a second manager

Tags: authentication, doctrine, symfony

I created a second manager for my second database.
In this base, i create a table which it contains my users.
The problem is the symfony don't load users from this database.

here is an extract of my config.yml :

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        seconddb:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "xx.xx.xx.xx"
            port:     "3306"
            dbname:   "acme_test"
            user:     "acmegamestest"
            password: "mypassword"
            charset:  UTF8

    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    entity_managers:
        default:      
           connection: default 
           mappings:
                acmeAdminBundle: ~
                acmeBlogBundle: ~
                gedmo_translatable:
                   type: annotation
                   alias: GedmoTranslatable
                   prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                   is_bundle: false
                   # make sure vendor library location is correct
                   dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
        seconddb:
           connection: seconddb
           mappings:
               acmeJoueurBundle: ~
```

and here is an extract of my security.yml :

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    Acme\JoueurBundle\Entity\Players:
        algorithm: sha512
        encode_as_base64: false

providers:
    seconddb:
        entity:
            class: Acme\JoueurBundle\Entity\Players
            property: username    
            manager_name: seconddb
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    administration:
        pattern: ^/admin
        provider: fos_userbundle
        context: administration
        form_login:
            #csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path : fos_user_security_login
            check_path : fos_user_security_check
            failure_path : null
            default_target_path : /admin                
        logout:       
          path : fos_user_security_logout
          target : /connexion
        anonymous: true    
    frontend:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: acme_joueurbundle
        context: frontend
        form_login:
            #csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path : acme_players_login
            check_path : acme_players_check
            failure_path : null
            default_target_path : acme_players_userprofile                      
        logout:       
          path : acme_players_logout
          target : acme_players_login
        anonymous:    true
```

and my entity implements "AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable"
with this function  :

```
 //////////////////////////liaison pour symfony////////////////////////////

public function getRoles()
{
     return array('ROLE_PLAYERS');
}

public function getSalt(){

    return $this->salt;
}

public function eraseCredentials(){

}

public function isAccountNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
    return true;
}

public function isAccountNonLocked()
{

    return !$this->banned;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->active;
}



    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->active
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->active
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

However when i trying to connect, i get this errors in dump function :

[image]

and in the section Doctrine i get this :

[image]

Is what you know the solution?
Hope you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

So, the error comes from this piece of code in the user authentication provider :

```
try {
    $user = $this->retrieveUser($username, $token);
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
    if ($this->hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials.', 0, $e);
    }
    $e->setUsername($username);
    throw $e;
}
```

The method retrieveUser failed and it throws bad crendentials exception. This explains why there is no connection since it has not yet been called.

Before asking you for the code of your provider, let's look at your security.yml because you create a provider called seconddb and in your firewall frontend you try to call a provider acme_joueurbundle who propably doesn't exist.

So, your security.yml should look like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml

[...]

providers:
    seconddb:
        entity:
            class: Acme\JoueurBundle\Entity\Players
            property: username    
            manager_name: seconddb
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    administration:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        [...]
    frontend:
        provider: seconddb
        [...]
```

Comment: no change!! it don't work.very strange!!the FOSuserbundle, i use it for the administration of the website and AcmeJoueurBundle, i use it for players in Frontend!!

Comment: Ok, I did not understand ... I thought you could not connect to the second database. Your question has nothing to do with the Doctrine connection that already seems to work ... You would have to add your entity (at least the important parts) so that we can help you.Maybe the password or salt fields are too small in the database and the strings are truncated. Maybe your twig form is incorrectly formatted. There are many possible reasons.

Comment: yes, when i try to connect with form login, the dump return me "bad credentials" and i get the impression that the symfony don't load entity players,No sql query is launched in my second manager but the config is correct